# parallel transport composition

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Is it correct that $$P_b^cP_a^bv = P_a^cv,$$
where $P_a^b$ denote parallel transport operator from $T_a\mathcal{M}$ to $T_b\mathcal{M}$ and $v\in T_a\mathcal{M}$?

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is not true. A standard counterexample is by taking $\mathcal{M}$ to be the round sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ and take $\gamma_i$, $i=1,2,3$, to be the three sides of a triangle on the sphere where each side is an arc of a great circle.

For example, we can take $a,c$ to be two points on the equator and $b$ to be the north pole such that the arc $ac=\gamma_3$ is 1/4 of the equator. Now if we take $v$ to be pointing in the direction of the arc $ab=\gamma_1$, then it can be seen that $P^c_bP^b_av\neq P^c_av$. They differ by a rotation of $90$ degrees.

(Sorry I don't have a photo here, but it is not difficult to have the picture in mind.)

Comment: thanks, i think i understand

Answer (score 2):

Here is a picture to help you understand

[image]

Comment: sorry, the picture is broke, can you upload this picture one more

Comment: Sorry i don't understand you can't see the picture ?

Comment: yes, i can't see the picture, it is broke

Comment: Does it work [here](https://files.mtstatic.com/site_4539/9712/0?Expires=1556278923&Signature=Nh-s62LhBsxhgRkQAy9aSgYp904PjiMRx70Pf5ZVtXJno8I-3deoSTEACfvznX37p4BftV5gEW0vR0TqsFBjaKdqhrDf3l2SvZ~b1Av5NW2WPKlolgKiwc5yaC03cnuj1SeP68WjZPsrlLeFSMrItzC5KzIsFDHatfKdW253yEk_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJ5Y6AV4GI7A555NA) ?

Comment: Yes, thanks, the picture is great, i absolute understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that $P$ is parallel transport along a fixed curve $\gamma$ then yes. You can apply directly the uniqueness result about parallel transport, i.e. given a curve $\gamma:I \rightarrow M$, $t_0 \in I$ and $u \in T_{\gamma(t_0)}M$, then there exists a unique parallel vector field $X$, such that $X(t_0)=u$.

Comment: In my setting, $P_a^b(v)$ mean tranport $v$ from $T_a\mathcal{M}$ to $T_b\mathcal{M}$ along a fixed curve $\gamma_1$.  in addition, $P_b^c$ and $P_a^c$ are correpond to $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_3$ respectively. all curve are geodesic.  I want to know whether the above equation is satisfied